# How to control Banshee playback speed?

Tags: software-recommendation, banshee, media-manager

Is there a way to control playback speed in Banshee? I want to play some videos and pod-casts faster or some video-tutorials slower - without changing the pitch - but can't find a build-in function or a plug-in.

The reason behind this question is amazing Banshee's library, therefore alternative answer would include suggestions for a media player capable of:

1. watching assigned library paths (preferably separate for audio books, videos, music, podcasts),
2. keeping play-counts and ratings inside each media file as a standard consistent ID3v1 or ID3v2 (or at least calling a user defined script after each database change so I could sync them myself),
3. changing the playback speed without affecting the pitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, looks like Banshee can not do this.

I found this [topic](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/audio-book-playback-td4651055.html) dated april 9th 2013.